# How to make Ubuntu 16 on a USB stick force hp smart array P400 to use the hpsa driver

Tags: system-installation

I have been having problems loading Ubuntu 16 on an HP proliantDL385 G5. I get as far as the partitioning and then get I/O errors.

What files do I need to change on the USB to fix this?

Comment: I/O errors suggest a problem with the drives.

Comment: I was told i need to change from cciss to hpsa drivers and that might solve the problem. I need to set it so it ignores the cciss and use the hpsa instead.

Comment: HP proliantDL385 G5 is a certified hardware for Linux servers, not only Ubuntu. No additional drivers should be required. "hpsa" drivers have been in the kernel since 2009, "cciss" is long gone, not used and not included for more than a decade. You're definitely barking at the wrong tree.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **CelticWarrior**'s remark.
 Try another USB to see if the I/O errors persist. If they do, you may have a serious hardware problem in your Proliant.

Comment: It actually loads from the usb so i think the usb is ok. I am wondering if the i/o errors could not be due to loading the wrong drivers

Comment: It may load, but that is no guarantee its loading all bytes correctly.  Again as suggested before, I/O errors commonly point to hardware. I would try another USB, just to make sure. Or at least do a binary compare of the USB and the source file(s).